# Want to disable warnings in the error_log , i tried all possible methods but it keep coming

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, cpanel

I have a wordpress based system hosted on interserver.net , my site keep generating ***error_log*** file due to the ***php warnings and notices***

I want to disable those so error_log file should not consume disk usage.

I tried following methods but none of them working for me.

1. in wpconfig i put following code

> ini_set('error_reporting', 0);

> also tried: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);

2. From cpanel in php settings tried following, that creates user.ini & php.ini

> error_reporting(0);

> then i tried which gives error in htaccess: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE)

> then i tried: error_reporting(E_ERROR)

i am not sure if any specific thing if i have to put in .htaccess file?
please help me

Comment: Don't disable them: fix them!

Comment: Depends on the warning and notices but may be out of your control if using Wordpress and 3rd party plugins. They should be addressed however, not ignored. Also if you have log rotation enabled then the log file sizes should be managed. More info from your host about log rotation here: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/cpanel-log-rotation-configuration/

Comment: @Bossman let me check sir, thank you for your useful advice.

Comment: @Bossman yes i did that by turning off rotation for now.

Answer (score 0):

**Turning off PHP Errors on WordPress**

For this part, you will need to edit the wp-config.php file.

Inside your wp-config.php file, look for the following line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

It is also possible, that this line is already set to false. In that case, you’ll see the following code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

In either case, you need to replace this line with the following code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Comment: Yes sir i did the same and still as it is, but let me double check.

Comment: no it does not work :-(